# Chutzpah - getting "Error: One or more errors occurred." in chutzpah.json

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, chutzpah

I am working on a .NET project and using Angular 1.5 with TypeScript at client side. For test case execution and code coverage I am using Jasmine + Chutzpah. Chutzpah is integrated with Visual Studio 2013.

In my project number of client side test cases are 1400+. Now I have started facing issues with Test case discovery and client side code coverage. With current Chutzpah.json file test cases are not getting discovered but when I change the path to specific file it starts discovering test cases. Please find chutzpah.json below:

```
{
  "Framework":"jasmine",
  "TestFileTimeout":"3600000",
  "ExpandReferenceComments": "false",
  "ExpandTestFileBatching":"true",
  "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
  "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
  "Compile": { 
     "Mode": "External",
     "Extensions": [".ts"],
     "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [".d.ts"]
  },
  "References": [
       {"Path": "Scripts/require.js"},
       {"Path": "Scripts/angular.js"}
  ],

  "Tests": [
     {"Path": "app/TestCases/"}
  ],

  "CodeCoverageIncludes": ["app/module1/controllers/*.ts",     "app/module1/module2/*.ts"],
  "CodeCoverageExcludes": ["*.d.ts", "Scripts/*", "*Spec.ts"],
  "EnableCodeCoverage": "true"   
}
```

Now with above chutzpah.json I get timeout error where as when I provide complete file name in "Path" for "Tests" It start dicovering test cases.

```
"Tests": [
     {"Path": "app/TestCases/testCaseSpec.ts"}
  ]
```

Also I have installed utilities from VisualStudio gallery to integrate test cases execution and code coverage in visual studio itself but I am not able to get it.  When I try to get code coverage by right click on TestCases folder and selecting "show code coverage", it says 710 passed, 54 failed Total 764. But I have more than 1400 test cases. Not sure why it only runs for 764.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, some of your properties are wrong.

1. It is EnableTestFileBatching not ExpandTestFileBatching
2. EnableCodeCoverage is deprecated, please just omit that. By default Chutzpah will run chutzpah when you ask it too. If you want it to always run use this property

   "CodeCoverageExecutionMode": "Manual|Always|Never",

At first glance I suggest a couple edits. Put "IsTestFrameworkFile": true on your two references. This will make sure chutzpah puts them before the coverage engine (Blanket).

Also, what is in the TestCases folder? Is it just tests or other files?

Comment: Thanks Matthew. It was quite helpful.